# How firebase http function to return snapshot to swift app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, httprequest, geofirestore

I have a firebase function performing a query and filtering by a geohash search radius.  It's working but I am returning Json and what I really want to do is return a snapshot. I am new to firebase functions.

Here is my firebase function

```
var GeoFirestore = require('geofirestore').GeoFirestore;

exports.geoQueryWitningRadius = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

 const data = req.body;
 const lat = data.lat;
 const lon = data.lon;
 const radius = data.radius;

 const firestore = admin.firestore();
 const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(firestore);
 const geocollection = geofirestore.collection('pickups');
 const query = geocollection.near({ center: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(lat, lon), radius: 
 radius });
 await query.get().then((snapshot) => { 
    return res.send(snapshot)
 }).catch(error => {
     console.log('error', error); 
 });
```

});

Here is my http request in swift

```
static func getGeoHashPickups(radius: Int, completion: @escaping([String: Any]?, String?) -> Void)  { //url, Error
    
    let parameters : [String : Any] = [
        "lat" : UserService.user.lat,
        "lon" : UserService.user.lon,
        "radius" : radius
    ]
    let url = "https://us-central1-app-request-ect"        
    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let dict):
                guard let dictionary = dict as? [String : Any] else { return }
                completion(dictionary, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil, error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert what comes back to my front end to a snapshot?

Comment: Answer to your concrete questions is below. But it sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right now, so we might be able to help better if you edit your question (or post a new one) on *what* you're trying to accomplish with the information you get back from the Cloud Function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was just trying to not duplicate my snapshot parsing by writing additional code to parse raw JSON. - Wow! I just realized who this is -  I love your videos, please keep up the great work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions cannot send back a `DocumentSnapshot` as that type is not serializable. And there is no way to convert the JSON back to a `DocumentSnapshot` in the Swift code.

But what you get boils down to the data of that snapshot, which should be enough. If you're missing something in the data returned, you'll have to also return that additional information from your Cloud Functions code, so the Swift code can pick it up.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to be sure I wasn't creating extra work for myself. I can see I have everything I need in the JSON coming back so I will parse it.