# Swift Firestore query with filter for documents near me

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I have an iOS app that has employees that need to be notified of pickups nearby. I want to perform a Firestore query and filter the radius of documents returned. I came up with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110141/how-firebase-http-function-to-return-snapshot-to-swift-app?noredirect=1#comment115111091_65110141)

but @Frank van Puffelen pointed out my question may be an x y problem and he was right!

I want is to listen to firebase Firestore for documents added then return results near my location. My documents have geopoint and geohash data. Is there a way to write a query in swift that has a listener attached and filters for documents within 100 miles?  This is my current query in swift:

```
extension Firestore {
    var pickups: Query {
        return collection("pickups").whereField("employeeUID", isEqualTo: "none").order(by: 
"date")
    }
}
func getPickups() {
    listener = db.pickups.addSnapshotListener({ (snap, error) in
        guard let documents = snap?.documents else { return }
        for document in documents {
            let data = document.data()
            let newPickup = PickUps(data: data) 
            self.pickups.append(newPickup)
        }
    })
}
```

Any ideas about a query would be greatly appreciated - Thank you!

Comment: Firestore has no built-in mechanism for querying documents near to a location. Since you already tagged with `geofirestore` did you look at using one of those libraries?

Comment: I'm trying out geofirestore but I have to use it with a firebase HTTPS request. whereas the code above just acts as an observer and sends my employees updated pickups. I think I could use geofirestore if I found some way to notify my users a new pickup is added to firestore.  I don't see a way to add a snapshot listener to geofirestore